# How to drop column from organize by column table in DB2?

Tags: db2, drop

Please help how to drop column from organized by column table is it possible to drop i by alter table drop column?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t issue an `ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN` statement to drop a column from a column-organized table.

If you need to drop a column, you’d need to create a new table without the new column and populate it from the existing table using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement.